# how to implement sorting in html table without using plugin in php

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

i want to code a table with searching sorting and pagination.
and all this three operation should connected with each other.
i have write a code for search and pagination 
but i am not able to add sorting logic in that
can anybody please guide a easy way to perform this 
this is my code

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
$records_per_page=10;

    $name = "";
    $email= "";

    $queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["search"])) {
        foreach($_POST["search"] as $k=>$v){
            if(!empty($v)) {

                $queryCases = array("name","email");
                if(in_array($k,$queryCases)) {
                    if(!empty($queryCondition)) {
                        $queryCondition .= " AND ";
                    } else {
                        $queryCondition .= " WHERE ";
                    }
                }
                switch($k) {
                    case "name":
                        $name = $v;
                        $queryCondition .= "username LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
                        break;
                    case "email":
                        $email = $v;
                        $queryCondition .= "user_email LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//if(isset($_POST["order"]))
//{
//    $order=$_POST["order"];
//    
//}
// else{
//    $order="user_id";
//}
//if(isset($_POST["by"])){
//   $by=$_POST["by"]; 
//if($by=="asc" & !isset($_POST["page"])){
//     $by="desc";
//    
//            }else if($by=="desc" & !isset($_POST["page"]))
//                {
//                
//                $by="asc";
//                
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                     $by=$_POST["by"]; 
//                }
//}
//else
//{
//    $by="asc";
//}
    $orderby = " ORDER BY $order $by"; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register " . $queryCondition;
    $href = 'demo2.php';                    

    $perPage = 10; 
    $page = 1;
    if(isset($_POST['page'])){
        $page = $_POST['page'];
    }
    $start = ($page-1)*$perPage;
    if($start < 0) $start = 0;  
    $query =  $sql . $orderby .  " limit " . $start . "," . $perPage; 
//  $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       


    if(!empty($resultset)) {
        $resultset["perpage"] = showperpage($sql, $perPage, $href,$order,$by);
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="user-grid">      
            <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="demo2.php">
            <div class="search-box">
            <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="search[name]" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"  /><input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="search[email]" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"    /><input type="submit" name="go" class="btnSearch" value="Search"><input type="reset" class="btnSearch" value="Reset" onclick="window.location='demo2.php'"></p>
            </div>

            <table id="tbl">
        <thead>
                    <tr>

<!--  <th><a href='demo2.php?by=<?php// echo $by; ?>&order=user_id'>Id</a></th>

 <th><a href='demo2.php?by=<?php// echo $by; ?>&order=username'>UserName</a></th>

    <th><a href='demo2.php?by=<?php// echo $by; ?>&order=user_email'>Email</a></th>

    <th><a href='demo2.php?by=<?php// echo $by; ?>&order=user_contact'>Phno.</a></th>-->
  <th><input type="submit" name="id"  value="user_no" class="btn-link"/></th>

 <th><input type="submit" name="username"  value="username" class="btn-link"/></th>

    <th><input type="submit" name="user_email"  value="user_email" class="btn-link"/></th>

    <th><input type="submit" name="user_contact"  value="user_contact" class="btn-link"/></th>



                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        foreach($resultset as $k=>$v) {
                        if(is_numeric($k)) {
                    ?>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $resultset[$k]["user_no"]; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $resultset[$k]["username"]; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $resultset[$k]["user_email"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $resultset[$k]["user_contact"]; ?></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    if(isset($resultset["perpage"])) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" align=right> <?php echo $resultset["perpage"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                <tbody>
            </table>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php


    function perpage($count, $per_page = '10',$href) {
        $output = '';

        if(!isset($_POST["page"])) $_POST["page"] = 1;
        if($per_page != 0)
        $pages  = ceil($count/$per_page);
        if($pages>1) {



            for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {

                if($_POST["page"] == $i)
                    $output = $output . '<span id='.$i.'  >'.$i.'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page"  value="' . $i . '" />';
                                    //$output=$output.'<a href="demo2.php?page='.$i.'&by=$by&order=$order">' .$i. ' </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }



        }
        return $output;
    }

    function showperpage($sql, $per_page = 10, $href,$order,$by) {
        $result  = mysql_query($sql);
        $count   = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $perpage = perpage($count, $per_page,$href);
        return $perpage;
    }

?>
<style>
#tbl
{
width:500px;
border:1px solid #00a2d1;
margin-top:10px;
}

#tbl tr {
  background: #fff
}

#tbl td{
border:1px solid #00a2d1
}

#tbl th
{
background: #00a2d1;
border:1px solid #fff
}
#frmSearch button[type="submit"]{


background-color:#00a2d1;
color:#fff

}
.btn-link{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#0000EE;
  padding:0;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:inherit;
}
</style>
```

how to add sort logic in this i want when user click on table header it should be switch between asc n desc and in every table header.

Answer (score 0):

Without plugin, you should use your own javascript. I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zscQy/446/). This might help

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding plugins?

Answer (score -1):

Check datatables working example
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

The Javascript shown below is used to initialise the table shown in this example:

-------------Javascript-----------------------

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

```
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

-------------------HTML---------------------------

The HTML shown below is the raw HTML table element, before it has been enhanced by DataTables:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

-------------CSS-----------------------

The following CSS library files are loaded for use in this example to provide the styling of the table:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).